# Combining several Word documents and sorting by header/subheader

Tags: microsoft-word, merge, bullets

Each month, I put together a monthly report for my supervisor. The report has achievements from the past month of 6 departments. Under each department are several subheaders for different projects and initiatives. So for example, say under the Marketing department, there is a "So-and-so conference" subheader and a "Media outreach" subheader, and under those are 4 or 5 bullet points each.

I've been asked to create a master report for the year up to October. Is there a way I can combine the documents and have them automatically sort by header/subheader, so that I won't have to go in and manually copy and paste them from 7 or 8 documents. There are dozens of subheaders on the large document, and it would be great to avoid this becoming a gigantic pain/waste of a day. Please let me know if you know a solution.

Thanks a ton

Comment: Could you share us excerpts of your documents?